# Keyword not supported: 'datasource'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use the last `connectionString` with name `sqlConString`.

This is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-saroh-20170305155508;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-saroh-20170305155508.mdf" />
    <add name="crowdfundingEntities4" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\crowdfunding.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="userdataEntities6" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\userdata.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="sqlConString" connectionString="DataSource=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\crowdfunding.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: <add name="sqlConString" connectionString="DataSource=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\crowdfunding.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;"/>

Comment: Umm, where is your connection string? There is fixed it.

Comment: Anyone please check the string???

Comment: He is showing "SqlDependency.Start(con);" in red color with showing above error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is connection string `Data Source` has a space between the word but your setting is `DataSource`

so try

`<add name="sqlConString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\crowdfunding.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;"/>`

If that does not solve your problem, then try:

1. provide a `providerName`
   if you are using normal ado .net then it should be `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` or
   if using entity framework need to add`providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` with adding `metadata` part in connection string (refer to your `userdataEntities6`)
2. if you are using entity framework, a part from adding `providerName` and modifying `connectionString` to include `metadata` also try change `&quot;` to `'`
   more info about this, check out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2008/12/09/explicit-connection-string-for-ef/

Comment: Bro i have try everything but it is still not working!!

Comment: @tassawar does any of your other connection string work? If it works, try use that and modify part relevant.  I always copy a working connection string and modify it to avoid typo or silly mistake.  I can't think anything else other than this